# How to download specifc rows when using Tableau Desktop?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

- We are using Tableau 2022
- We are aware we can use the DOWNLOAD object to download the data from a sheet.
- We know we can even rigtht-click on a specific sheet row (when inside the Dashboard) then select "View Data" and from there click on the DOWNLOAD button to finally select the default ".csv" format etc.

**QUESTION** : Could we minimize these steps for the users by allowing them let's say to click on a specific row of data and then clicking on a download BUTTON that would allow us to do the same but in less steps ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible using an extension : https://exchange.tableau.com/products/25

[image]

All credit goes to Information Lab UK, for making this user-friendly tool. I can assist you to integrate this if needed

Comment: Hi and thank you for this amazing information. It works for some sheets i tested on BESIDES the one sheet i really need. SITUATION: There is a sheet onto which we can click on a specific cell (Numbers) that will display this other sheet with 1 row. When testing the  EXPORT ALL extension it does NOT work like with the other sheets. Do you or someone know why that might be ?

Comment: I think i can help you out if we connect over Zoom, You can "Hire Me" here : https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar/vizzes

Comment: Hi and thank you for the offer i didn't know we also had the opportunity to hire. This is a first for me. I will keep that in mind if i can't make this one sheet work with this great extension by the way. Props to you and the developers of it. Thank you